# OpenLayers Full Screen control not working

Tags: openlayers, mapcontrol

I have a problem with OpenLayers controls. I have two controls which are perfectly working,

```
var mousePositionControl = new ol.control.MousePosition({
        coordinateFormat: ol.coordinate.createStringXY(6),
        projection: 'EPSG:4326',
        // comment the following two lines to have the mouse position
        // be placed within the map.
        className: 'custom-mouse-position',
        target: document.getElementById('mouse-position'),
        undefinedHTML: 'Haritada degilsiniz.'
    });
    var scaleLine = new ol.control.ScaleLine();
```

...

```
controls: ol.control.defaults().extend([mousePositionControl, scaleLine])
```

But when I try add fullscreen control as a third one, like this:

```
var fullScreen = new ol.control.FullScreen();
```

and edit controls like this:

```
controls: ol.control.defaults().extend([mousePositionControl, scaleLine, fullScreen])
```

it's not working and also I lose `map.on('click', function(event)){...}` functions.

By the way I try to add only FullScreen control, it works. Have a limitation there of adding controls on OpenLayers 3?

Answer (score 0):

I think you may need to add custom controls to default ones instead of extending it.

 Can you try like this ?

```
..
controls: ol.control.defaults({}, [
   new ol.control.FullScreen(),
   ..others if you want to..
})
..
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it's not working. FYI. But I try

`map.addControl(new ol.control.FullScreen());`

and it's work perfectly.